# Which formula was used to get Gravitational Waves animation?

Tags: general-relativity, simulations, computational-physics, gravitational-waves

I would like to make animation like this by myself

[image]

It is from wikipedia article "Gravitational wave".

But if I use formula from wikipedia article "Gravitational wave" subsection "7.2.2 Wave amplitudes from the Earth–Sun system".

```
h = -1/R*G^2/c^4*2*m1*m2/r*(1+cos^2(theta))*cos(2*omega*(t - R/c))
```

I get picture with round waves, but not spiral one.

My question is where to find formulas to get this spiral gravitational waves like in wikipedia?

Comment: If you look at an individual radial cross section, that's just an ordinary wave. The phase of these waves varies with the angle as you go around the center. Try this in Wolfram Alpha: "sin(sqrt(x*x+y*y) - ArcTan[x,y]), x=-20 to 20". I don't have access to the pro version, so I can't do the animation, but it's basically just a rotation.

Comment: this formula (sin(sqrt(xx+yy) - ArcTan[x,y])) is not real physics formula. It is a fake formula how to reproduce the similar animation. I would like to find real physics formula.

Comment: The wikipedia animation is fake. It has nothing to do with real physics. You said you wanted to get "gravitational waves like in wikipedia"... and that's what that is. The real formulas are a lot more complex and you won't have too much fun trying to animate those because of the quadrupole nature of gravitational waves. Even a simplified image will look like this: http://www-tc.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/next/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/gravitational-waves.jpeg and if you want to see the actual structure of the wave, it will be more like this: http://www.universetoday.com/127255/gravitational-waves-101/

Comment: @CuriousOne If you take a look of the equation cited, it is not of a spiral form $sin(k r-\theta)$ you mentioned. The effective part $r$ and $\theta$ at any given time is separated.

Comment: @hwlau: I didn't look at the equation, at all. The formula I gave produces a spiral. None of this has anything to do with physics, of course. It's all about how to produce a pleasing image, so this is really more cgi arts and crafts. If you wanted me to produce animations of a real gravitational wave, then I would have to break out my GR books and start reading for about a month, or so. Maybe one of the relativists has a set of formulas ready to go...

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks for clarification. I did not know that wikipedia has fake picture. In this case what is the formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave#Wave_amplitudes_from_the_Earth.E2.80.93Sun_system for h+ and hx?

Comment: eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/astro616/lectures/lecture_ch21.pdf has a very quick introduction to the way gravitational wave polarization is being described and you can find the definition of the plus and cross-polarization amplitudes on page 1203. There is nothing wrong with simplifying images, by the way. They are trying to introduce visual concepts that the human mind can use later when analyzing the full mathematical description of the problem. This wikipedia animation is, admittedly, grossly oversimplifying, but then, a more precise animation is no more helpful, IMHO.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks for good article. And this animation in Wikipedia is it simplified version of Gravitational Wave's amplitude of plus polarization in x-y plane or something else?